# Check and remove null values in array

Tags: angular

I have an array that I am trying to check for null values. If there are any, I would like to remove them from the array. Here is my code and attempt.

```
this.existingSavings = [{
    value: null,
    sourceId: null,
    fund: null
}];

changeSavingsAmount(): void {
    for(let i = 0; i < this.existingSavings.length; i++) {
      if(this.existingSavings[i].value == null) {
        //not sure what to do here
      }
    }
}

<div *ngFor="let source of existingSavings; let i = index;" class="row">
   <div class="col-4">
     <div class="input-container">
        <label for="savings">Existing savings value</label>
        <input id="savings" [(ngModel)]="existingSavings[i].value" (blur)="changeSavingsAmount()" type="number"
          placeholder="R">
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to check the `value` property, you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```js
changeSavingsAmount(): void {
    this.existingSavings = this.existingSavings.filter(s => s.value != null);
}
```

Just be careful, as this is only checking the `value` property of each element in your array of object. The other two properties aren't checked, and neither is the element itself. You could do that with:

```js
filter(s => s != null && s.value != null && s.sourceId != null && s.fund != null);
```

Comment: A final note: in case the changes aren't picked up, try: `this.existingSavings = [...this.existingSavings.filter(s => whatever you put here)]`. This creates a new array and changes the reference of `this.existingSavings` and is more likely to be picked up by Angular's change detection.

Answer (score 1):

You can also check it using forEach and ignore the null items as below.

```
changeSavingsAmount(): void {
    const existingSavings = [];
    this.existingSavings.forEach(exSave => {
      if (exSave[i].value != null) {
         existingSavings.push(exSave);
      }
    });
    this.existingSavings = existingSavings;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

solution using splice

in your ts file

```
existingSavings = [
    {
      value: null,
      sourceId: null,
      fund: null
    },
    {
      value: "f",
      sourceId: "dd",
      fund: null
    },
    {
      value: 't',
      sourceId: 'uu',
      fund: null
    }
  ];
  constructor() {
    var d = this.removeByAttr(this.existingSavings, "value", null);
    console.log(d);
  }
  removeByAttr(arr: any, attr: any, value: any) {
    var i = arr.length;
    while (i--) {
      if (
        arr[i] &&
        arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) &&
        (arguments.length > 2 && arr[i][attr] === value)
      ) {
        arr.splice(i, 1);
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }
```